# Answer from the person that asked the question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had asked one question and I had not received any answer so after a lot of search I found a solution. My question now is that if someone asks a question and after a while finds the answer which he had been looking for, should he accept it or wait if someone else gives another answer? After all he can change the accepted mark if there is a better one.

Comment: Closely related: [How do we handle Question and Answer by the same user in quick succession?](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/127/how-do-we-handle-question-and-answer-by-the-same-user-in-quick-succession)

Comment: I had the same experience on one of my questions. Someone pointed me to the "help" drop down on the top of the page. Years of unhelpful help had blocked it from my vision, but the help on this site is /actually/ helpful.

Comment: I knew that I can answer it as I had seen a lot of these. The purpose of my question was to see if you consider it right to accept your own question or wait in case someone else answers it. Something like that cannot be found in the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you may accept your own answer.

If a new one comes along later you will be able to change your choice if you think it's better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 14):

From our very own [emacs.SE Help Center](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> ## Can I answer my own question?
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> [To encourage people to do this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time.
>
> You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!

Comment: Thanks it is enlightening!